# Debye Theory for Solids

Tags: statistics, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

[problem image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9N2jq.png)

I don't know how to calculate the derivative function (15.10).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: To deal with the messy algebra, it might be helpful to define $z = \dfrac{T_D}{T}$, so that $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial T} = -\dfrac{1}{T_D}z^2\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}$.

Comment: You need to know how $V$ and $T$ are related to the other parameters for this. What does holding $V$ constant tell you about the dependence of the other parameters? Your snippet doesn't include this information, so we cannot answer it.

Comment: I solved it. Thanks anyway.